# Searches in Outlook (exchange server) hang

Tags: exchange, outlook, search

We are currently using Exchange version 14.3 (Build 123.4).

It seems that every day when I come in users are complaining that search is not working in Outlook (confirmed on my machine). Users are using a variety of Outlook versions, but most are on 2010 or 2013. None of them are using it in cached mode.

I'm not sure what is actually getting it going again, but I've been trying the following:

Restarting the following services: "Microsoft Search (Exchange)", and "Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology" (plus all the services that require them). Between the two it seems to cover a fair amount of the exchange services.

<del>The first day searches started working sometime shortly after I did that. All the others, I ended up doing ".\ResetSearchIndex.ps1 -force -all" from the shell. Granted it can take some time after resetting the index for it to build up again and work - if that is even fixing it at all. Perhaps just the time it is taking me to do those tasks is fixing the problem.</del>

It appears that ResetSearchIndex.ps1 is not necessary - but one of the services that restarts with "Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology" is (though not either of those restarted with "Microsoft Search (Exchange)").

Running `Test-ExchangeSearch -Identity <username> -Verbose` yields a MapiExecption "Unable to SetSear" before the message gets cut off the console window and this:

```
    VERBOSE: [14:36:32.975 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Initializing Active Directory server settings for the remote Windows
    PowerShell session.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.162 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Active Directory session settings for 'Test-ExchangeSearch' are: View
     Entire Forest: 'False', Default Scope: 'domain.com', Configuration Domain Controller:
    'gc.domain.com', Preferred Global Catalog: 'gc.domain.com', Preferred Domain
    Controllers: '{ gc.domain.com }'
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.162 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Runspace context: Executing user:
    domain.com/Users/ExchangeSearchAdmin, Executing user organization: , Current organization: , RBAC-enabled: Enabled.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.162 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Beginning processing &
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.381 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Instantiating handler with index 0 for cmdlet extension agent "Admin
    Audit Log Agent".
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.537 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Current ScopeSet is: { Recipient Read Scope: {{, }}, Recipient Write
    Scopes: {{, }}, Configuration Read Scope: {{, }}, Configuration Write Scope(s): {{, }, }, Exclusive Recipient Scope(s):
     {}, Exclusive Configuration Scope(s): {} }
    VERBOSE: [14:36:33.599 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Searching objects "user" of type "ADUser" under the root "$null".
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.192 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Previous operation run on domain controller
    'gc.domain.com'.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.207 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Processing object "domain.com/Org Name/Users/User Name".
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.738 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Searching objects "Mailbox Database" of type "MailboxDatabase" under
    the root "$null".
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.785 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Previous operation run on domain controller
    'gc.domain.com'.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.831 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Admin Audit Log: Entered Handler:Validate.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.847 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Admin Audit Log: Entered ClassFactory:InitializeConfig.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:34.925 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Admin Audit Log: Exited ClassFactory:InitializeConfig.
    VERBOSE: Testing Exchange Search.
    VERBOSE: [14:36:35.206 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Resolved current organization: .
    VERBOSE: [14:38:36.061 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Getting catalog state for Mailbox Database "Mailbox Database"...
    VERBOSE: [14:38:36.124 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Catalog state: Notifications.
    VERBOSE: [14:38:36.139 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Getting the indexing state for mailbox "User Name" ...
    VERBOSE: [14:38:36.155 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Mailbox state: Done, Crawl start time: 2015-03-30T13:32:00.
    VERBOSE: [14:38:36.748 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Getting the message indexing state...
    VERBOSE: [14:38:37.653 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Document state: Queued, state = 0.
    VERBOSE: [14:38:37.668 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : TimeSinceLastNotificationWasIndexed for MDB Mailbox Database is 337
    seconds.

    Database     Server       Mailbox      ResultFound SearchTime Error
                                                       InSeconds
    --------     ------       -------      ----------- ---------- -----
    Mailbox D... SERVER-NAME  User Name... False       -1         Time out for test thread.
    VERBOSE: [14:38:37.777 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Admin Audit Log: Entered Handler:OnComplete.
    VERBOSE: [14:38:37.840 GMT] Test-ExchangeSearch : Ending processing &
```

Comment: Since you're in online mode, I'm assuming you are using the Exchange search. What is the result of the command `Test-ExchangeSearch -Identity <username>`

Comment: It is currently working (ran my fix for the day).  The results of running that are Result Found: True, In Seconds: 2.621.  We might have a different result if I run that when first thing in the morning - which is when we seem to have the issues.

Comment: As I thought, different result when during problem times.  Result Found: False, Error: Time out for test thread.  I saw a MapiException with something like "Unable to SetSear" before it got cut of the side of the window.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific - I could look through the event logs all day and it may be there but I'll miss it.  I'm a programmer, doing the job of an admin.  I'm seeing some exchange errors, but at this moment Test-ExchangeSearch is returning fine.

Comment: Which OS are you using for the Exchange server? What about the clients?

Comment: Server OS version: Win 2k8 R2 Enterprise.  Clients are Win7 & 1 Win8.1.

Comment: results of Test-ExchangeSearch -Identity <username> -Verbose ?

Comment: results added to the original question

Comment: We may or may not have solved the issue over the past weekend.  I've been giving it some time to prove the issue has been resolved.  If it is still working tomorrow, I will be posting back with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up contacting a 3rd party to help with our problem as my research was getting nowhere.

The technician started off retrying everything that was mentioned in the question, and the comments.

Turns out the build information wasn't 100% accurate, as I pulled it from the wrong source.  The real build information revealed we were on Rollup 8.

The technician suggested we install Rollup 9 (the latest).  I did this on Saturday.  On Monday, the search wasn't giving errors like the original problem, but it wasn't giving proper results either. So I ran ResetSearchIndex.ps1 again to rebuild the search index.

Ever since the index was rebuilt, it has been running fine (3 days now), where the problem used to happen daily.  Looks like Rollup 9 fixed whatever issue we were having.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a full rebuild of the index after installing an update rollup, (a time consuming operation) you can try to repair the indexing engine:

Go to Program and Features (or launch appwiz.cpl) and select "Microsoft Full Text Indexing Engine for Exchange" on the Exchange server and select Repair.

Give it a few minutes and the function will start to work again.

If that doesn't work, then go ahead with the index rebuild—running ResetSearchIndex.ps1 from the Exchange Management Console.